# Is it possible to configure vagrant to use a box mirror?

Tags: download, vagrant

I'm trying to try out Vagrant, but ...

```
$  vagrant init hashicorp/precise32
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.

$  vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'hashicorp/precise32'
    default: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/precise32
==> default: Adding box 'hashicorp/precise32' (v1.0.0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise32/versions/1.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box
    default: Progress: 3% (Rate: 62598/s, Estimated time remaining: 0:52:14)
```

62K/s is pretty much the fastest its been for multiple boxes I've tried including `hashicorp/precise32`, `hashicorp/precise64`, `bento/debian-8.2` and some others.

Is there a Vagrant box mirror that I can configure vagrant to use or some other mechanism to allow for faster box downloads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `wget` on the URL as

```
wget https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise32/versions/1.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box
```

There has been [issue](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5319) opened related to this without clear fix. vagrant uses curl internally but it might work better using wget instead.

once you have the box file you still need to add to vagrant (`vagrant box add ...`)